# How do I load multiple classes from a module folder in Angular2 TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, module, angular

I have an Angular2 application with the following module structure:

```
/app
    /content
        /models
            resource.ts
            container.ts
            entity-type.ts
            index.ts

        /services
            /whatever
                whatever.service.ts
```

My models `index.ts` looks like:

```
export * from './resource';
export * from './container';
export * from './entity-type';
```

I want to be able to load all the models into `whatever.service.ts`.

```
import {Resource, Container} from '../../models';
```

The barrels loading portion of my `system-config.js` files looks like:

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/content',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

TypeScript compiles this without error, however, in the browser I get the following errors from the System loader and Zone saying certain files can't be found.

> GET http://localhost:4200/app/content/models.js 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM59771:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>   zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/app/content/models.js
>           at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
>           at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
>           at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
>       Error loading http://localhost:4200/app/content/models.js as "../../models" from http://localhost:4200/app/content/services/container/container.service.js ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/app/content/models.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>   zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/app/content/models.js(…)

When I import each model directly from it's `.ts` file, everything works.

```
import { EntityType } from '../../models/entity-type';
import { Container } from '../../models/container';
```

How can I import modules without causing errors in Angular2?

Comment: Rename your `index.ts` to `index.d.ts`

Comment: @Andzhik that didn't seem to make any difference. I'm getting the same errors from SystemJS in the browser saying `models.js` can't be found.

Comment: I added my barrels list from the system-config.js file to hopefully shed some light on why these modules aren't loading.

Answer (score 16):

From what I can tell this is probably what you want:

./model/index.ts would look something like this:

```
export * from './resource';
export * from './container';
export * from './entity-type';
```

Then lets say you want to import it from your  whatever.service.ts

whatever.service.ts would look like this:

```
import {Resource, Container} from '../models';
```

since you are specifying an index file in the models folder. You should be able to just import the folder. As specified above.

Hope this is clearer.

Comment: [This is actually how Angular 2 does the exports for its scoped packages](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#barrel). It's a good approach :)

Comment: this is what my index.ts already looks like. I've updated my question to include that.

Comment: Your doing:
import {Resource, Container} from '../../models';

isnt it back one level so:
import {Resource, Container} from '../models';

Comment: This didn't solve the issue. The path seems to be correct since it must be that way to compile the TypeScript. So it must be a System loader issue instead?

Comment: Why is this not finally accepted as answer! God how I hate sloppy people!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `.ts` is the `models` folder:

New file `all_models.ts`:

```
import * from './entity-type';
import * from './container';
 ...
```

Then you'll be able to do:

```
import {Resource, Container} from '../../models/all_models';
```

The only issue here is to remember to keep `all_modules.ts` up to date and add references to any new `.ts` file with models.

Comment: This answer gave me a "ts" file I could find at the top of my file list, for me it is a little cleaner than index.ts.  Also the "import" statements are supposed to "export".  please correct and I will remove the last part of this comment