# using angular 2 CLI, how can I use absolute paths so I don't have to use import { .. } from '../../../shared/thing'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I created my project using angular 2 CLI.  However I am wondering how I can stop using the crazy imports like

```
import { SomeSharedComponent } from '../../../shared/some-shared-component';
```

I am using what the angular cli generated for me.  So, is it possible to use something like

`import { SomeComponent } from 'app/shared/components/some-component'`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use TypeScript v2.0 or newer (still in beta). The reason is that it gives you the ability to use [path mappings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039).

This would allow you to define a path map named `app-shared` and then use that to point to the desired shared component: `app-shared/some-shared-component`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolve it by using a symbolic link referencing the shared folder. You should also add it to system-config.js.

```
import { SomeSharedComponent  } from './shared/';
```

with the following declaration in system-config.js.

```
const barrels: string[] = [
   (...)

    // App specific barrels.
    'app',
    'app/shared',
    /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

I would be interested by a cleaner solution.

**Edit:**

You should also include an index.ts in the shared folder with the following content.

```
export * from './some-shared-component';
```

Then you can use the import statement without the name of the component.

```
import SomeSharedComponent from ''../../../shared/'
```

However, it still requires the relative path part.

I have made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RjOGsKlDIQnRl79qu7fd?p=preview) to clarify the usage from the Angular2 hero tutorial. See in particular the following files.

```
app/relative/hero-relative.component.ts
app/shared/my-shared.component.ts
app/hero-search.component.ts
```

You should have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1301) about the Angular2 style guide. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751672/how-do-i-load-multiple-classes-from-a-module-folder-in-angular2-typescript) could also be interesting.

I think for a complete solution (without relative path) we will have to wait until webpack module manager is adopted by Angular CLI as stated in the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1465). A [webpack preview](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md) is already available.

Comment: I believe that TS tooling (IDE's) won't like this solution

Comment: I've added that component there, but the issue is that I am 2 levels inside a component that is unique for a particular feature.  From here, I want to import something from src/app/shared.  So Basically, I am inside src/some-feature/shared/components/some-dumb-component.  And from here, I want to import something that's in src/app/shared/components

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux I find that interesting that Intellij can traverse those paths to find that import via the system configuration... cool

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux can you please tell me how the barrels work?  I have barrels like that too.  For exmaple, the shared component I want to use is in barrels as `app/shared/components/list-item`, but if I do `import {ListItemComponent} from 'app/shared/components/list-item'` it says it cannot find that module.

Comment: I have made a Plunker to clarify the usage of barrel (see the edit of the answer).